# Operate with large numbers in LibreOffice BASIC

Tags: libreoffice, basic

I'm trying to operate the MOD of a number but it returns overflow data type.

This operation works:

```
VariableDouble = 2147483647 - (97 * (2147483647 \ 97))
MsgBox VariableDouble
```

This operation returns error:

```
VariableDouble = 2147483648 - (97 * (2147483648 \ 97))
MsgBox VariableDouble
```

Shouldn't be Double data type larger than Long one? Of course, variable declaration is as follows: `Dim VariableDouble As Double`.

It happens the same if I use the built-in operator MOD: `a MOD b`.

I need to do operations with 10 digits numbers. Is there a way I can do this using BASIC? What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution making my own MOD implementation [partially] with an iterative bucle. It works —I didn't test it using numbers with a lenght greater than 50 digits, though—, so this is the code:

```
Dim LargeNumber As Double
Dim result As Integer
Dim dividend As Integer
Dim index As Integer

For index = 1 To Len(LargeNumber)
    dividend = result & Mid(LargeNumber, index, 1)
    result = dividend Mod 97
Next
```

It seems BASIC can't operate with large numbers, despite it can save them into variables. An another solution would be to call Python externally (API can do that). Python is awesome, however I need to keep the portability of this database for several systems (some use Windows OS so won't have Python preinstalled).

Comment: This looks like a good solution for Basic.  However, Python should be fine, as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

From https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Using_Python_on_Windows: "If you do not customize the installation, Python-UNO bridge is installed as default on recent version."  So a dependence on Python should be portable.

```py
def big_numbers():
    dividend = 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
    divisor = 97
    modulus = dividend % divisor
    rounded_val = modulus * divisor
    result = dividend - rounded_val
    oDoc = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()  # the current Writer document
    oVC = oDoc.getCurrentController().getViewCursor()
    output = ("%d - (%d * (%d \ %d)) = %d\n" %
        (dividend, divisor, dividend, divisor, result))
    oDoc.getText().insertString(oVC, output, False)

g_exportedScripts = (big_numbers,)
```

See https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python_as_a_macro_language for how to run this code.

Related: https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=39854.

Comment: Oh, Python portability is very nice! I will have it in mind for next scripts. This is a very good point for LibreOffice suite.